# Problem with pass data to the controller with view model ( two list )

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I create a view and create two cards to show new skill and current skill.
The problem is `TittleNewSkillEHS` back to the controller cero data after I select a new skill.

Short description of my request
I will need to display two lists with information about New Skill (required checkbox to select and add current skill), Current skill (required update target).

One approached to solution the request I create a view model take EmployeeTitle id, Title name, and two list
•   List Current skills
•   List New skills
.
.
.

```
TitleSkillVM TitleSkillVMNew = new TitleSkillVM();

TitleSkillVMNew.TitleId = SelectTitle.TitleId;
TitleSkillVMNew.TitleDescription = SelectTitle.TitleName;
TitleSkillVMNew.TittleNewSkillEHS = _tempNewEHS;   “New skill”
TitleSkillVMNew.TittleSkillEHS = _tempEHS;   “List Current skill”
return View(TitleSkillVMNew);
}
```

```
@model WCMApps.Models.ViewModel.TitleSkillVM

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form asp-controller="AdmTitles" asp-action="InsertNewSkillTarget" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="TitleId" />
            <%: Html.HiddenIndexerInputForModel() %>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="TittleNewSkillEHS" />

            <div class=" card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <h4>New Skill Index</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    Skill  Name
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    Current Target
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.TittleNewSkillEHS)
                            {
                                if (item.TitleSkillTargetStatus == true)
                                {
                                    <tr class="table-info">
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsSelectedNewSkillTitle, item.TitleSkillTargetId)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.TitleSkillTargetId)
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SkillLevelDDescription)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SkillLevelDDescription)
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Target)
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Target)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("InsertNewSkillTarget", "AdmTitles", Model.TittleNewSkillEHS)'">Save</button>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form asp-controller="AdmTitles" asp-action="UpdateCurrentSkillTarget" method="post">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <h4>Current Skill Index</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    Skill  Name
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    Current Target
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col">
                                    Target
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.TittleSkillEHS)
                            {
                                if (item.TitleSkillTargetStatus == true)
                                {
                                    <tr class="table-success">
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SkillLevelDDescription)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Target)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input asp-for="Target" class="form-control" />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="Target" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UpdateCurrentSkillTarget", "AdmTitles", Model.TittleSkillEHS)'">Update</button>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to pass TittleNewSkillEHS to Controller:

View:

```
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-9">
                    <h4>New Skill Index</h4>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">


        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th></th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        Skill  Name
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        Current Target

                    </th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{ var count = 0;}
                @foreach (var item in Model.TittleNewSkillEHS)
                {

                    if (item.TitleSkillTargetStatus == true)
                    {
                        <tr class="table-info">
                            <td>
                                @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsSelectedNewSkillTitle, new { @name = "TittleNewSkillEHS[@count].IsSelectedNewSkillTitle" })
                                @Html.CheckBox("IsChecked", new { @name = "TittleNewSkillEHS[@count].IsSelectedNewSkillTitle" })*@
                                <input asp-for=@item.IsSelectedNewSkillTitle name="TittleNewSkillEHS[@count].IsSelectedNewSkillTitle"/>
                                <input name="TittleNewSkillEHS[@count].TitleSkillTargetId" value=@item.TitleSkillTargetId hidden />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SkillLevelDDescription)
                                <input name="TittleNewSkillEHS[@count].SkillLevelDDescription" value=@item.SkillLevelDDescription hidden />
                                @*@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SkillLevelDDescription)*@
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Target)
                                <input name="TittleNewSkillEHS[@count].Target" value=@item.Target hidden />
                                @*@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Target)*@
                            </td>





                        </tr>
                        count++;
                    }


                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">



            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Save</button>


        </small>
    </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult InsertNewSkillTarget(TitleSkillVM t) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]